# Cannot terminate for loop in terminal

Tags: terminal, process, gnome-terminal, for

I was running a for loop in terminal which has a sox command in it. For some reason the sox command failed and now I cannot terminate the for loop. I tried pressing Ctrl+c many times, Ctrl+z many times but no use.

I can't get the prompt, terminal just stays like that. There is no `sox` process running in the background as per `ps aux` How to deal with this case, I don't want to close the tab but fix the problem by some other means.

```
$ for spkr in /home/user/tmp/*; do  filesIn1Line=`tr '\n' ' ' < $spkr`; sox $filesIn1Line en_$spkr.wav; echo $spkr; done

sox FAIL formats: can't open output file `en_/home/user/file1.wav': No such file or directory
^C^C^C^C^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^Z^C^C^C^C^C^C^C
^C^C^C^C^C^Z^Z^X^X^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^C^
```

Comment: Try `C-\ ` to send a SIGQUIT. This often works when `C-c` doesn't, for various reasons. If that doesn't work, you could find the bash process and kill it manually, if you wanted.

Comment: @TomHunt thanks, tried that didn't work. How do I find the bash process for a `for` loop?

Comment: Killing the `bash` process would cause the terminal to exit, which was what you did not want to do.